# How to sort a list of tuples by the first element in each tuple, and pick the tuple with the largest last element in each group

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples

Here I have a list of n k-tuples (Here I set n = 4, k = 5)

```
A = [(1, 3, 5, 6, 6), (0, 1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 9, 8, 3, 5), (0, 2, 3, 5, 7)]
```

I hope to sort these tuples by their first element, so it will be 2 groups. And in each group, I want to select only 1 tuple whose last element is the largest. So in this situation, I hope my output of the function to be a list of tuple, such as

```
[(1, 3, 5, 6, 6),
 (0, 2, 3, 5, 7)]
```

Below is my attempt, and it seems it does not work well

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def f (sample):

    data = pd.DataFrame(sample)
    grouped_data = data.groupby(0)
    maximums = grouped_data.max(4)
    result = list(maximums.to_records(index = False))
    
    return result
```

I want to know if this could be accomplished by writing a dict? If so, how?
Any hint or help is welcome.

Comment: A small remark, typo: ``numpy``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for this:

```py
import itertools


def by_first_element(t):
    return t[0]


def by_last_element(t):
    return t[-1]


sorted_A = sorted(A, key=by_first_element)
groups = [[*g] for _, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_A, key=by_first_element)]
max_of_each_group = [max(g, key=by_last_element) for g in groups]
```

Output:

```py
[(0, 2, 3, 5, 7), (1, 3, 5, 6, 6)]
```

Alternatively, yes, you can use a dictionary:

```py
groups = {}
for t in A:
    groups[t[0]] = groups.get(t[0], []) + [t]

max_of_each_group = [max(g, key=lambda t: t[-1]) for g in groups.values()]
```

If you want `max_of_each_group` sorted, then

```py
>>> sorted(max_of_each_group, key=lambda t: t[0])
[(0, 2, 3, 5, 7), (1, 3, 5, 6, 6)]
```

Comment: Thank you. But my professor gives the hint that trying to use dictionary, besides he asks us not to use packages other than numpy and pandas

Comment: @Cooper see my edit, I've added a dictionary solution.

Comment: PS - `itertools` comes with the standard library, it's not an external package, just in case your professor is making that distinction.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial to accomplish with a dict. In fact, since you are going to do a reduction operation on the group, you can do this quite space-efficiently doing the reduction at each step:

```
>>> A = [(1, 3, 5, 6, 6), (0, 1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 9, 8, 3, 5), (0, 2, 3, 5, 7)]
>>> result = {}
>>> for tup in A:
...     first = tup[0]
...     result[first] = max(tup, result.get(first, tup), key=lambda x:x[-1])
...
>>> result
{1: (1, 3, 5, 6, 6), 0: (0, 2, 3, 5, 7)}
>>> list(result.values())
[(1, 3, 5, 6, 6), (0, 2, 3, 5, 7)]
```

Another valid approach is to do the grouping step first then a reduction step, this is probably more generalizable:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> grouper = {}
>>> for tup in A:
...     grouper.setdefault(tup[0],[]).append(tup)
...
>>> grouper
{1: [(1, 3, 5, 6, 6), (1, 9, 8, 3, 5)], 0: [(0, 1, 2, 4, 5), (0, 2, 3, 5, 7)]}
```

And to reduce:

```
>>> {k: max(v, key=lambda x:x[-1]) for k,v in grouper.items()}
{1: (1, 3, 5, 6, 6), 0: (0, 2, 3, 5, 7)}
```

Comment: Instead of finding max in every iteration, isn't it faster to do it like: for tup in A:
        if tup[0] in result.keys():
            if tup[-1] > result[tup[0]][-1]:
                result[tup[0]] = tup
        else:
            result[tup[0]] = tup. Of course, your solution is much faster than mine, so it's still better.

Comment: @NewbieAF I don't think it makes a big difference either way, but sure, you can do it like that, but I think the above is concise and clear. Edit, as an aside, no need for `.keys`

Comment: Thank you so much