# Grouping lists based on a certain value in python and then returning the minimum of the group

Tags: python, list, minimum, group

I have a list that looks this:

```
lst = [(1,23,45,18),(1,42,15,5),(1,29,65,91),(2,35,62,7),(2,72,39,6),(2,41,15,81),(3,45,61,23),(3,41,15,69),(3,12,15,1)]
```

I'd like to group the lists by the first indicee, so group 1 would be:

```
[(1,23,45,18),(1,42,15,5),(1,29,65,91)]
```

and then return the list has the minimum value in the 4th indicee (18, 5 or 91). So the result for group 1 would be:

```
(1,42,15,5)
```

Ideally the resulting list would be the list of minimums:

```
final_lst = [(1,42,15,5),(2,72,39,6),(3,12,15,1)]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, Melanie?

Comment: I updated your post and replace `list` by `lst`. Don't use builtin as variable name, please.

Comment: Related: [How to sort a list of tuples by the first element in each tuple, and pick the tuple with the largest last element in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69398250/how-to-sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-the-first-element-in-each-tuple-and-pick-the-tu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lst` is sorted by the first elements (if not first sort using `lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])`), then you could use `itertools.groupby` to group the lists by the first element, then use `min` with a key that compares each group by the last elements:

```
from itertools import groupby
out = [min(g, key=lambda x: x[-1]) for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0])]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 42, 15, 5), (2, 72, 39, 6), (3, 12, 15, 1)]
```

Or if the number of tuples for each index is the same, we could get the desired outcome with `sorted` + list slicing:

```
out = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[-1]))[::3]
```

Comment: Sort the list first?

Comment: @wwii I assumed it was sorted because it appears like that in the input but now that I re-read the question, nowhere does it say it's sorted.